# How do I navigate from my MainPage and refresh it?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, runtime

I navigate from my SecondPage to my MainPage like this:

```
private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            if (rootFrame != null && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                rootFrame.GoBack();
            }
        }
```

but the aplications crashes because in my MainPage I have a `<CaptureElement>` that I need to refresh. So I want to know how to refresh my MainPage after I navigate to it.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask than edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

override OnNavigatedTo()

is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a page load or page prerender in your main page. Please inform [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) source.

Example from msdn:

```
public MyPage()
{
   Load += new EventHandler(Page_Load);
}
```

Comment: No, I guess my problem is in the Capture Element, because when I was working with Silverlight the Video Brush worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

Your app might be crashing due to captureElement. try debugging that and see the exception. It would give the actual reason for crashing.